# Rspec Error: Not reading my extended method in Array

Tags: ruby, rspec

I keep getting `Undefined method all_empty?` error. Did I open the class incorrectly?

core_extensions.rb

```
class Array
    def all_empty?
        self.all? { |element| element.to_s.empty? }
    end
end
```

core_extensions_spec.rb:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe Array do 
    context "#all_empty?" do
        it "returns true if all elements of the Array are empty" do
            expect(["","",""].all_empty?).to be true
        end

        it "returns false if some of the Array elements are not empty" do
            expect(["","1", Object.new, :a].all_empty?).to be false
        end

        it "returns true for an empty Array" do
            expect([].all_empty?).to be true
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Is where a `core_extension.rb` live? Do you include it in the test environment?

Comment: Your extension is not loaded (in test env)

Comment: What you mean by live? How do I know I included it in the test environment? Do you guys mean the require 'path/core_extensions.rb'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `require_relative 'path/to/core_extensions.rb'` in your core_extensions_spec.rb.

If you need `core_extensions.rb` in other tests, you can add this line to your `spec_helper.rb`.

Comment: This worked, but I'm confused, isn't it meant to work that you don't need to require the file? since you extended the class, or am I just dumb?

Comment: You're not dumb. The code needs to be executed in order to extend the Array class. There are probably many hundred rb scripts on your computer, how should Ruby know which one to interpret? You either have to manually require all the files you need, or let some magic happen with Rails autoload or Rspec which loads all the *_spec.rb files.

Comment: I see, I don't why I though it doesn't need requiring, Thanks